# Salesforce Lightning: Sorry to Interrupt Popup

Tags: lightning, error-messages

Okay, so this only happens every once in a while and I don't seem to see a pattern as to when it happens or what I am doing while it happens. If I am navigating through Lightning, sometimes this window will popup.

[image: SorryToInterruptPopUp]

And then if I click on the Technical Stuff, the following expands:

```
Uncaught Action failed: ui$inputSelect$controller$doInit [TypeError: Cannot read property 'Decision_Making__c' of null]
throws at https://na34.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ/aura_prod.js:1:27
at xz.z.set (https://na34.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ/aura_prod.js:293:221)
at b.K.set (https://na34.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ/aura_prod.js:214:232)
at L.set (https://na34.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ/aura_prod.js:161:104)
at xz.z.set (https://na34.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ/aura_prod.js:293:252)
at b.K.set (https://na34.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ/aura_prod.js:214:232)
at Object.updateValueFromOptions (https://na34.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22LTX5y5GOICnl_zeBOa0nnQ%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22YN%22%7D/app.js:111:105)
at Object.init (https://na34.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22LTX5y5GOICnl_zeBOa0nnQ%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22YN%22%7D/app.js:1390:131)
at doInit (https://na34.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22LTX5y5GOICnl_zeBOa0nnQ%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_US%22%2C%22en%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22YN%22%7D/app.js:104:752)
at G.qc (https://na34.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ/aura_prod.js:275:170)
at Array.c (https://na34.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ot_aUc3gWVJCViXm5-AclQ/aura_prod.js:228:170)
```

Can anyone help with this? I am completely lost on this one.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Have you tried filing a case with support?

Comment: I have not, wanted to exhaust this option first before taking that route. @AdrianLarson

Comment: Are you using `<ltng:require />`? See [this Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000183G6QAI).

Comment: Yeah I saw that  Known Issue, but this is not my instance, so I have no idea if or where that would be being used.

Comment: Also, I just checked and this instance has 0 custom components that that could be used in. So that is not it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some related `Known Issues`:

1. [Lightning Experience - Summer '16 - forceSearch$entitySelector$controller$init [TypeError: Cannot read property 'xx' of null]](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000184YaQAI)
   **Status**: IN REVIEW
   **Workaround**: Use Classic
2. **[Lightning Experience - Summer '16 - ui$inputSelect$controller$doInit [TypeError: Cannot read property 'xx' of null]](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000184YVQAY)**
   **Status**: IN REVIEW
   **Workaround**: Use Classic
3. [Lightning - Internal Server Error & Sorry to Interrupt errors appear when doing a Search for Products](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000186fqQAA)
   **Status**: SCHEDULED - WINTER '17
   **Workaround**: Use Classic
4. [Error window pops up when navigating to certain pages in Lightning](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000183G6QAI)
   **Status**: SCHEDULED - SUMMER '16 PATCH 15.0
   **Workaround**: Use Classic

It looks like you're affected by the second of these. Unfortunately the only listed workaround is to use classic.

Comment: I like how the Workarounds for all of these are use classic. lol

Comment: Yep, truly unfortunate. I think you're stuck behind door #2 fwiw.

Comment: Yeah I think I am going to have to agree with you. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also pretty funny that the repro tells you to *Navigate until you receive an error message.* Yay. @cmmoutes13

Comment: Haha yeah, because they clearly have no idea what is causing this issue.